# Dual Display - one is fine, the other showing squashed in left half of the screen

Tags: xrandr, xinit

I have a Debian linux box set up with two displays. 
One is from Display Port (DP) on the box through an active adapter to DVI input on the display itself.
The other is straight VGA to VGA.. This is the problem one.

Both displays are detected and both have same resolution (1920x1080)

```
  Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1280mm x 720mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1280x1024     75.02    70.00    60.02
   1280x800      59.81
   1024x768      75.08    72.00    70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    75.00    70.01    60.32
   640x480       75.00    72.81    70.03    60.00
   720x400       70.08
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 983mm x 576mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88
   1600x900      59.98
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1360x768      59.80
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00
   720x400       70.08
```

I'm using xinitrc to run the displays at startup

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of VGA1

chromium -disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --kiosk --disable-sync-preferences --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars http://localhost/folder/file1.html &
chromium -disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --kiosk --user-data-dir=/home/user/chrome2 --disable-sync-preferences --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars http://localhost/folder/file2.html
```

The problem I have is that, while the DP display is working fine, the VGA display is only using the left half of the screen and the content is squashed to fit in that half despite the fact I have configured the same resolution in xinitrc that is detected when I manually run xrandr.

What am I doing wrong/How can I get the VGA display to use the whole width of the screen?

Comment: It may be a panning issue. Sometimes graphics cards set panning as default. Can you try: `xrandr --fb 3840x1080 --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --panning 1920x1080 --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of VGA1`